# How can I get Google rank for a website from my script?

Tags: php, seo, google-ranking

I'm wondering how can I get the Google ranking for a specific page from my PHP script.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my posted URL to a PHP script i found and tested working.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588751/php-script-to-show-google-ranking-results where this question is already answered.

Comment: @codescape Thanks, I searched before posting but I couldn't find it. The code works. How can I accept your answer? :)

Comment: Glad to hear! You cannot accept a comment as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havn't tested it, but it looks like the function I used years ago.

http://pastebin.com/v6MdDszM

Comment: Sorry, they may have disabled the algorithm. I just my old coding and it doesn't appear to work anymore either.